# SonarQube detects non closing tag error even though the code has one

Tags: javascript, php, html, sonarqube, tags

When I'm working with a PHP application and checked for SonarQube issues...I have found an error in html code saying All Html tags must be closed at tags html , head and body.

[image]

How to fix this?

I have already checked for the closing </html>, </head>, </body> tags at the end of the page and it definitely have them.
I have already checked for any other closing tags (div) are missing and I found none.
Also checked for the misalignment of closing tags if any and everything was fine. Is the issue may be because of the SonarQube rules...?
Note: This issue is occur in only 3 html code files where there are a lot more html files in the Project.